# Solving StochasticDifferential Equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Please help me in solving this Stochastic Differential Equation for $Y_t$

$$dY_t = a Y_t dt+ b dX_t \qquad Y(0) = c $$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.
Also find the $\mathbb{E}[Y_t]$ and $\text{var}[Y_t]$.

I have tried to write the Ito Lemma for general $Y_t$ function in the two variables $t$ and $X_t$
and then tried to compare the coeficients  term of $dt$ and $dX_t$ but not getting any proper result.

Thanks,

Comment: what is $X_t$ here, isn't i Brownian motion?

Comment: Yes Xt is Brownian motion.

Comment: Check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process)

Comment: This resembles OU process. Do I need to apply Fokker Planck method.. But is it the complete solution steps? .

Comment: I would try variation method described on wiki.

Comment: Ok, @IIya. Thanks. ya variation method is simpler . I will also try to get this.

Comment: Your question is a particular case of this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/813755/ (set $c=0$ there)

Comment: why not general linear SDE? not yet discussed in class and hence not allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the integrating-factor approach, where $\mu_t = e^{-a t}$.

Rewrite the original SDE as:
$$ d\left( \mu_t Y_t \right) = \mu_t \, b \, dX_t \, .$$

$Y_t$ can be obtained as
$$ Y_t = \frac{b}{\mu_t} \int_0^t \mu_s \, dX_s + \frac{\mu_0 Y_0}{\mu_t} = b\, e^{a t} \int_0^t e^{-a s} dX_s + c \, e^{a t} \, .$$

Comment: $\mu_t Y_t = Y_0 + b\int_0^t \mu_s dX_s$. Then $Y_t = \frac{c}{\mu_t} +  \frac{b}{\mu_t}\int_0^t \mu_s dX_s$

Comment: @Gordon: good point; I made the corrections.